# Uninstalling Issue

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I installed ubuntu through a Usb stick. I didn't create any partition for it. 
I'm not sure of where ubuntu has been installed now. 
I did not have any data loss on any of the local drive volumes after installation of ubuntu. 
i want to uninstall it. How should I proceed with it ?

Comment: If you didn't create a partition and you didn't lose any data, where exactly did you install Ubuntu? Are you sure you didn't just run it from the usb stick?

Comment: No USB's.I'm a 100% sure.. i get the Grub loader on starting my desktop.

Comment: Using [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gparted/), and/or `fdisk -l`, please add your partition layout to your question. Also note, you can't remove Ubuntu from within Ubuntu. Is it dual booted with anything, or are you using [Wubi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29)? - If you remove Ubuntu from a Windows Dual boot, you need a Windows disk or something to repair the Master Boot record, or you won't be able to boot...

Comment: yes, it is dual booted with Windows 7. and no. i'm not using Wubi. 
I seem to have two empty partitions in the disk management options. 
one is a 14gb partition and the other one is a 4gb partition. How can i find out if ubuntu has been installed on them.
They do not show up on ubuntu filesystem or the windows one. 
Just within the disk management utility.

Comment: As wilf says, use GParted and have a look at your partitions. It should say what they are.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GParted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gparted/) to find the relevant partitions - the ones with the `/boot`, `/` and `/home` mount points may be the ones you want to remove. Here is a complicated example I borrowed:
[image]

Note down things like size, position etc, so it is easier to identify when in Windows Disk Manager, remembering that is a [very different view on things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I2Az.png).

Backup any data you want on the Ubuntu install.

Then, follow the steps in this answer for the steps to remove Ubuntu:

[How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Following the steps on **'To Remove Grub'**, and **'To delete the Ubuntu Partitions'** should work. Hopefully the Windows Disk Manager has enough sense to stop you removing anything important... *(to Windows anyway)*